# How to “write” string value to existing plist file in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have “myPlist.plist” file which contains items which have the key “isFavorite” as string.

I am using the following code to SUCCESSFULLY filter for “isFavorite” key which has the string value of “YES”:

```
func SearchYES(){
    let pathMC = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("myPlist", ofType: "plist")
    let dictMC = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: pathMC!)
    myPlist = dictMC!["Questions"]!.mutableCopy() as? Array

    if let questionArray = the! as? [[String:AnyObject]] {
        let isFavorite = questionArray.filter({
            if let favorite = $0["isFavorite"] as? String {
                return favorite.uppercaseString == "YES"
            }
            return false
        })
        print("Total number of exam items: \(isFavorite.count)")
    }
}}
```

Thus, I know how to read or retrieve my data properly, BUT I don’t know how to WRITE ON my pList programatically.

For instance, I tried using the following code:

```
let isFavoriteKey = "isFavorite"
var isFavoriteValue: String! = "NO"

@IBAction func isFavoriteButton(sender: UIButton) {
isFavoriteValue = "YES"
saveFavoriteData()
}

func saveFavoriteData() {
let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String
    let fullPathName = documentDirectory.stringByAppendingPathComponent("myPlist.plist")
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(fullPathName) {
        if let dictionaryForPlist = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: fullPathName){
         dictionaryForPlist.setObject(isFavoriteValue!, forKey: isFavoriteKey)
            dictionaryForPlist.writeToFile(path, atomically: false)
}
```

I got the code (and tweaked it a little) from http://rebeloper.com/read-write-plist-file-swift/ and http://www.learncoredata.com/plist/.

BUT THEY AREN’T WORKING. It does not “write” anything to my existing “myPlist.plist” file.
Does anyone know how to actually “write” data or set string values on an existing plist file?
For instance, in my "myPlist.plist" file, all items have the key "isFavorite" (String Value) and I wanted to programatically WRITE the string value of whether it is a "YES" or "NO" using the click of a button.

Comment: You like caps lock don't you?

Comment: Yep, to emphasize my point :)

Comment: Can you confirm by breakpoint that  if let dictionaryForPlist = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: fullPathName){ evaluates to dictionary. I suspect there may be bug with your paths as the code for writing the dictionary on disk and setting the value seems correct.

Comment: I have updated my tutorial at http://rebeloper.com/read-write-plist-file-swift/ to Swift 3.1. Go ahead and take a look at it.